# Rubymine: How to jump back?

Tags: ide, rubymine

It's really great Rubymine allows us to Cmd+Left-Click to trace where a method is defined and jump to the source file/location.

I doubt if there's a hot-key to go back, which is helpful when there're a lot of files/tabs are opened or viewing a long file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an action to go back, `Navigate` | `Back`:

[image: back]

Hotkey would depend on your keymap and can be observed in the menu.

Comment: In osx (and RM 8.0.3) default is `cmd+[`

Comment: On MacOS (nee OSX) I prefer `cmd+[` over Ctrl+Alt+Left because some helper apps (e.g. Spyglass in my case) override Ctrl+Alt+Left and similar combinations.